# QlikView data sourcing from MySQL server on Linux via SSH

Tags: mysql, odbc, qlikview

How do we define ODBC for MySQL database running on Linux machine (AWS) for which we have to connect using SSH?

Basically, I have to get the data loaded into QlikView file. So I am not able to figure out do the connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access, then you could create an [SSH tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) from your QV machine to your Linux server. Since QV runs on Windows, you can use [Putty to create the tunnel](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/).

Basically an SSH tunnel maps a local port to a resource on a remote network using the server which you have SSH access to as a gateway. For example you can map port `3306` on your QV machine to port `3306` on the database server. The traffic between them is encrypted.

If you have a tunnel up and running, you can pretend that the MySQL server is running on the same machine as Qlikview and you can create a database connection by connecting to `localhost:3306`.

Comment: thanks. Thats what I did (Port forwarding) and it worked. I forgot to mention it here.